# Matlab: Run Matlab apps programmatically

Tags: matlab

I want to launch one of the apps included in my Matlab version called Classification Learner programmatically. How can this be done?

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
matlab.apputil.run('classificationLearner')
```

Comment: You need to use the appropriate ID returned by `matlab.apputil.getInstalledAppInfo`. See: [the documentation for `matlab.apputil.run`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.apputil.run.html)

Comment: Do you have MATLAB R2015a or newer and the Statistics Toolbox?

Comment: Yes 2016 with all the tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search for 'Classification Learner app MATLAB' tells me the following will do:

```
>>classificationLearner
```

Comment: This would be an applicable method of running it from the command line. The OP is asking how to run it from within another MatLab program, with a function call.

Comment: @Rayanth if the app is in MATLAB's [search path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html) or the current directory of the invoking function there is no difference. Given that [MATLAB's documentation explicitly states](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationlearner-app.html): `MATLAB command prompt: Enter classificationLearner`, it's a valid instruction assuming the toolbox is installed properly. If you don't know the software I'd say use caution when critiquing others on its use.

Comment: @excaza You make an assumption in your comment that the answerer does not make in the answer. I concede the point, though - I do know MATLAB, but I seem to be exhibiting lower brain function due to excessive use of C# lately.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but I'll let you know if this works for me

Comment: If it works , which it should would you kindly upvote it.

Comment: @SomeGuy if you can edit the question to remove the lock on my down vote, I'll gladly reverse it to an up vote. Perhaps some minor clarifying information?